# Saving a double array to a text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I have an array of floating point numbers which has an unknown length as the the array is dynamic (it grows as new data is added to it).  I need to find a way to store the data into a text file.

I would like the text file to be formatted in such a way that there is one floating point number per line.

I've been searching the web but could not find a solution, I'm new to c# so I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to solving the problem.

Comment: `I've been searching the web but could not find a solution` Unbelievable.

Comment: On a side note, a `List<float>` is likely better suited as your number of points can grow. (Resizing arrays is relatively expensive)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it in a single line in .NET 4.0, like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    @"c:\data\myfile.txt" // <<== Put the file name here
,   myDoubles.Select(d => d.ToString())
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using(StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("filename.txt"))
{
    foreach(var item in myArray)
    {
        sr.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the required using (using System.IO)

Comment: I didn't realize it was so simple, my Google search skills need some work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] values = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\out.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you repeat `Nikolay Kostov`'s answer?